Issue when opening a new buffer with plugins enabled
I have a plugin stored in ~/.vim/ftplugin/vhdl that I need while writing *.vhdl code. However, I don't really need it when, say, I am writing *.v code.
With VIM I use buffers, so for instance in one session I open test.vhd and a test.v files at the same time (i.e., :badd both). However, I can see the above plugin is loaded also when I execute :badd test.v.
How to make the file-type plugin loading when effectively working on *.vhdl only?
Many thanks

Could you tell us what is the filetype of your test.v buffer (:set ft?)? What are the symptômes that make you think the vhdl plugin is active on the test.h buffer (colorization key mapping, ...)?

Could tell us what is the vhdl plugin you are using such that we could reproduce your problem? Is it vim-hdl?

You can check if you only use buffer-local commands in your plugin: :setlocal for options, :noremap <buffer> for key bindings, etc.
